# DB Insert Laravel ID

Tags: laravel

Как в laravel используя конструкцию DB::table('table')->insert([]);
Вставить ID текущей записи? Используя следующий код, вместо $position должен быть ID записи:

```
DB::table('categories')->insert([
                'title' => $title,
                'slug' => $slug,
                'position' => $position
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
```

Comment: в чем проблема заменить `position` на `id` ?

Comment: Вопрос разве в этом? Пожалуйста воздержитесь от подобных вопросов, если не можете ответить по существу. Если вопрос стоит в извлечении ID и вставке в поле position, значит так надо!

Comment: если текущая это которая в запросе то надо id получать до ее вставки. например в pg что бы получить id - `DB::selectOne("select nextval('categories_id_seq'::regclass) as id;")->id`. но тогда нужно будет и в массив insert([]) добавить поле id